# Xamarin - Add title and button in action bar

Tags: android, ios, android-actionbar, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.form (Portable) having two project android and ios.

I want to add title in action bar which will change according to detail page also want to add one button in right side in action bar

I refer below link

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage

This link help me to create navigation page. but not able to add title and button in action bar

Below is image of action bar that I want. Payment is a title which can be change according to detail page and on right side "+" is button

[image]

Please suggest me how can I add title and button in action bar using xamarin form (Portable)

Comment: for tool bar you need to create   _saveAddToolBarItem = new ToolbarItem()
            { Icon = Constants.ASSES_PLUS_ICON, };
            _saveAddToolBarItem.Clicked += _saveAddImage_Clicked;

Comment: I dont want to add toolbar item. I change the question, added image so you can understand what i want

Comment: there no any other option you need to use toolbar to add plus icon

Comment: Can please you tell me how to add toolbar or sent me link? How can i change action bar color? I wrote this code but not changing the color of the action bar. 

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MUNI_Demo.View.Detail.Contact"
             Title="Contact"
             BackgroundColor="#42A990">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create page like there is not any other option to add plus sign without using a toolbar item in master detail page

Following is some sample code

```
public class TodoListPageCS : ContentPage
{
    private ToolbarItem _saveAddToolBarItem;

    public TodoListPageCS ()
    {

        Title = "Page Name";
        _saveAddToolBarItem = new ToolbarItem()
        { Text = "Save"};
        ToolbarItems.Add(_saveAddToolBarItem);
        _saveAddToolBarItem.Clicked += _saveAddToolBarItem_Clicked;
        Content = new StackLayout { 
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    Text = "Todo list data goes here",
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void _saveAddToolBarItem_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to create your own custom base page instead of content page

To changing toolbar color refer following link:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44586/navigationbar-background-image-renderer-android

[image]
Hop this code will help you

Approch to change toolbar color:

```
  Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType)) {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#42a990"),
                    BarTextColor = Color.White,
                };
```

Comment: Thanks it help me alot. Can you also tell me how to align center the title